# How can I get current project id in SonarQube plugin?

Tags: sonarqube

How can I get current project id from Ruby `ApplicationController` class?

The code is executed from **SonarQube** menu (`SECTION=Navigation::SECTION_RESOURCE`) so I cannot pass any parameters.

The ultimate goal is to check user's permissions for the current project, so if it can be done without project id it will be also a valid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by calling `Project.by_key(params[:id])` Sonar passes the the project key as `id` request parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Project id:

```
@project.id
```

Project key:

```
@project.key
```

Project name:

```
@project.name
```

Perms check:

```
  if has_role?(:user, @project)
```

Lifted from the [WidgetLab Plugin](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-widget-lab)

Note that you can have the widget's corresponding Java class return an absolute path to the file from `getTemplatePath` to do edit-erb/save/browser-refresh development.

E.G.

```
  @Override
  protected String getTemplatePath() {

    return "/path/to/plugin/src/main/resources/my_widget.html.erb";
//    return "/my_widget.html.erb";
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the widget to a global dashboard without specifying a project? In that case, project Id is nil because you've made a global, not a project-level widget.

Comment: No, the widget always asks for project name if added to the global dashboard.

Comment: Sorry @Sergey, I don't know what else to tell you expect to double-check your context. I've just run though this to make sure it works, and it does for me.

Comment: Your example for @project is from *.html.erb file, while I need it in the ApplicationController *.rb file. The controller is called from SonarQube menu directly and I cannot pass parameters to it.